# add html tags to a variable string

Tags: php, variables

lets say

```
$keyword = obama
$result = "US President Barack Obama on Wednesday signed a landmark law"
```

How do i make that everytime $keyword appears inside $result it changes the $keyword to be inside `<strong></strong>` tags?

str_replace doesn't work because if the keyword is in lowercaps and the result obama is in higuer caps it wouldnt replace it.

Thanks

edit: found the answer, in case anyone needs it this is the code

```
$myWords = array($keyword);
function boldText($arrWords, $strSubject)
{
     if (!is_array($arrWords)) return;
     foreach ($arrWords as $strWord)
     {
          $strSubject = preg_replace('@(' . preg_quote($strWord, '@') . ')@i', "<b>\\1</b>", $strSubject);
     }
     return $strSubject;
}
```

Comment: Beware using this approach if the source data is likely to contain any HTML or indeed URLs, etc. (e.g.: What happens in the word "obama" is in a URL.)

Comment: I take the $result from a string that is only a short description that doesn't contain any html neither is a url. the thing is i need to put it bold even if the string has caps letters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
function boldText($string, $array) {
  $string = strip_tags($string);
  return preg_replace('~('.implode('|', $array).'[a-zA-Z]{0,45})(?![^<]*[>])~is', '<strong>$0</strong>', $string );
}
?>
```

from http://php.bigresource.com/bold-string-from-array-of-keywords-HLRL2A8c.html

Comment: that didnt work :/ it removed all text and left only $string in bold.

Comment: works fine for me.
echo boldText('US President Barack Obama on Wednesday signed a landmark law',array('Obama'));

Comment: i finally got it from the same website you told me, but there was another code at the end of the page.. So thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
str_replace (ucfirst($keyword), "<strong>" . $keyword . "</strong">, $result);
```

or use a regex with case insensitive.

Comment: str_replace doesn't work because if the keyword is in lowercaps and the result obama is in higuer caps it wouldnt replace it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use str_replace:

```
str_replace ( mixed $keyword, mixed '<strong>' . $keyword . '</strong>', mixed $result)
```

This will replace the $keyword with itself, surrounded by `<strong>` tags.

Comment: str_replace doesn't work because if the keyword is in lowercaps and the result obama is in higuer caps, it wouldnt replace it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are probably other methods, but I'd use preg_replace().  Something like:

```
$result = preg_replace($keyword , "<strong>$keyword</strong>" , $result);
```